# Redundancy of notation in instance_variable_set, instance_variable_get

Tags: ruby

When I set or get instance variables using some name, for example `@foo`, I can do something like:

> instance_variable_set("@foo", some_value)
>   ...
>   instance_variable_get("@foo")

But often, I use a variable for the method name, which does not include the `@` prefix, so that I end up doing:

> method = :foo
>   ...
>   instance_variable_set("@#{method}", some_value)
>   ...
>   instance_variable_get("@#{method}")

But since all instance variables are prefixed with `@`, I think it redundant to have to type `"@#{method}"` instead of simply typing `method`. Why are the methods `instance_variable_set` and `instance_variable_get` not designed to accept string/symbol without `@` as its first argument like this:

> method = :foo
>   ...
>   instance_variable_set(method, some_value)
>   ...
>   instance_variable_get(method)

where the variable to be actually set will be `@foo` rather than `foo`?

Is there any advantage with the way it is?

Comment: Isn't using `instance_variable_(get|set)` a code smell?

Comment: `:"hello?"` is a valid symbol - is it a valid variable name?

Comment: @Grimm. It is not. My question was, why is it not designed to automatically prefix the string/symbol with "@". I added examples to make my question clearer.

Comment: If there are some valid symbols that would be converted into invalid instance variable names, could that be a reason?

Comment: @Grimm I thought about that, but if it would always be used without `@`, then there will be no problem. I was wondering why it could not be like `attr_(accessor|reader|writer)`, where you don't put `@`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, quite simply, that the instance variable is named `@foo`, not `foo`. The `@` is **part** of the variable name, just as the `$` is part of the global variable name `$foo`.

The reason that `@` is not necessary when calling `attr_accessor` and friends is because they define attribute methods, so it makes sense to provide the *method* names, not the variable names.

Of course there is no technical reason `instance_variable_set` cannot prepend the `@` itself. However, the method accepts a **symbol** that corresponds to the variable name. A symbol *by definition* represents the identifier with the given name. So the **only** symbol that corresponds to the instance variable `@foo` is `:@foo`. That is why you *have* to include the `@`, because we know that `:foo` does not correspond to any instance variable identifier at all. (And if you supply a string, it will be converted to a symbol internally first.)

**Update:** In the C Ruby implementation (MRI), there is actually no mention of `@` anywhere in the [code that handles instance variables](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/variable.c). Only the [*parser*](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y) knows instance variables start with a `@`. So it seems that separating code parsing from implementation is another possible reason.

Comment: Maybe this boils down to difference in philosophy.

Comment: I think it's more about semantics. Hopefully my updated answer makes it more clear (and also introduces another possible reason).

Comment: I am not convinced with your original answer, but the updated part convinces me. Thanks.